# Limit windows process memory/execution time with job objects - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, winapi, limit, jobs

I'm having an issue trying to make my application shut down after it has reached specified execution time. I created a job, set limit information, assigned current process to it and nothing happens.
My code:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
myJob = CreateJobObject(&sa, TEXT("oko"));
LARGE_INTEGER lint; 
lint.LowPart = 1;

JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION jbli;
jbli.PerProcessUserTimeLimit = lint;
jbli.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_TIME;
SetInformationJobObject(myJob, JobObjectBasicLimitInformation, &jbli, sizeof(jbli));

AssignProcessToJobObject(myJob, GetCurrentProcess());
```

I thought it would make my application shut down after 100 nanoseconds, but nothing happens. What is the problem here?

---

After hours of "fun" with winapi documentation I gave up on this approach and just created another process (which is actually even more convenient for my problem) with flags:

```
NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB
```

and such process can be assigned to the job. To succesfully create a job, I followed Roger Rowland's advice and explicitly set parameters of SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure. Default security attributes (NULL in CreateJobObject) work similiarly.

Comment: Are those calls succeeding? Also why are you setting lint to -1, don't you want 1?

Comment: So I tracked the results and found out that if I try to create the job object with empty SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, it fails, but if I go with NULL for defaults, I get an error trying to assign current process to the job. (code 5 - access denied) Should I check the job access rights or process access rights? And yes, I wanted 1 but tried also 0 and -1.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is *possibly* here

```
LARGE_INTEGER lint; 
lint.LowPart = 1;
```

You define a `LARGE_INTEGER` and initialise `LowPart` but do nothing with `HighPart` which may contain random data (in a Release build). Maybe try this

```
LARGE_INTEGER lint; 
lint.HighPart = 0;
lint.LowPart = 1;
```

Another possibility is here

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
myJob = CreateJobObject(&sa, TEXT("oko"));
```

because you haven't initialised the `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` structure. So do something like this instead

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
myJob = CreateJobObject(&sa, TEXT("oko"));
```

If either or both of these have no effect, perhaps you can edit your question accordingly and I'll think again. It's quite likely that you'll need a [more sophisticated initialisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` but start with the above and check all error returns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does the trick with the creation of the job, but then I'm still not able to assign current process to the job.

Comment: @Shocked - I expect you're getting some security related error? Can you get any info from `GetLastError`?